# Sendgrid Multipart emails Blank from Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, actionmailer, sendgrid

I was using only html emails which worked from my Rails 3.1.4 app, but I decided to add text only emails to make them multipart and now the email arrives blank.  I also started using Sendgrid's Heroku addon - not sure if that is part of it.

When I look in my heroku logs, I can see that both views, the .erb and .html.erb rendered successfully and I don't see any errors.  The email arrives, but the body is blank in Yahoo! and in Hotmail it only says (didn't do any more testing):

```
This is a multi-part message in MIME format...

----
```

here's my mailer:

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base

  helper :application
  default_url_options[:host] = "foo.com"

  # email on new user registration to verify user
  def verification_instructions(user)
     subject       "Email Verification"
     from          'Bar <info@bar.com>'

     @user = user
     recipients    "#{user.first_name} <#{user.email}>"
     sent_on       Time.now
 @url  = "http://bar.com/user_verifications_controller/show/#{user.perishable_token}"
  end
```

The text version (.erb)

```
Hi <%= @user.username %>, thanks for signing up

Please click the following link to verify your email address:                                           
<%= @url %>

If the above URL does not work, try copying and pasting it into your browser. If you continue to have problems, please feel free to contact us.
```

[I posted the html here.](https://gist.github.com/2721360)

Also, when I send the email from the console in development, I can look in the logs and see that renders the email.  [I put the output here.](https://gist.github.com/2765790) Tried a different email to make sure that it wasn't an issue specific to one email[2](https://gist.github.com/2765790)

Thanks in advance, for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just started using Sendgrid too....

I'm using the sendgrid gem

My Mailers have

"include SendGrid" at the top

and an exclpicit call to mail(subject: "Yadda", to: "recipient@mail.com") at the end of the method.